# How to access VM instance of GCP from my local machine?

Tags: cloud, ubuntu-16.04, google-cloud-platform

My local machine is running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have created a VM instance on Google Cloud Platform, which is also Ubuntu 16.04. How do I connect to this virtual machine from my own laptop terminal? I wish to install anaconda etc on my virtual machine so how do I 'access the VM's terminal from my local machine's terminal?'

Answer (score 2):

for connecting to GCP instance from local machine you've to setup **gcloud command-line tool** and select the default region and zone in local machine. This might help
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you generate a SSH key-pair(public+private) with PuttyGen.
2. Paste the contents of your public key in GCE in the SSH Key section. 
   [image]
3. Open Putty and enter the session details (username@instanceip) and don't forget to add in the Auth section the path to your private key.
   [image]

If you wish a more basic approach, then you need to employ the ssh command in a similar manner as below but not before registering your private key.

```
ssh remote_username@remote_host
```

Answer (score 1):

For using ssh command

1. create your ssh key if you dont have it
2. add the content of your ssh key to the instance settings, under SSH keys
3. `ssh -i ~/.ssh/<filename without .pub one> <your email without @gmail.com>@<your instance ip>`

replace `<content>` with your actual details